# How do I use Google API to add custom domain mapping in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-python-client

I am trying to add a custom domain mapping to my App Engine app using the Google API (not through console). However, I keep getting 403 forbidden error when the http request is made with the Discovery API Client. I have obtained a credentials json file from App Engine with owner permissions and I point to that with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable. Since I have full permissions, I'm guessing the problem is I'm not using the API correctly but haven't been able to see what is missing.

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.dirname(__file__) + str('/json_cred_file')

apps_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('appengine', 'v1beta')

response = apps_client.apps().domainMappings().create(
        appsId='apps/myappname', body=json.loads(
        '{"id": "newsubdomain.mydomain.com","sslSettings": '
        '{"sslManagementType": "AUTOMATIC"  }}')).execute()
```

Here is the error:

```
WARNING  2018-07-06 23:51:09,331 http.py:119] Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "forbidden"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Google support and the issue is when using the domain mapping function, the service account needs to be added to the search console as an owner. This is the search console: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

Answer (score 0):

They have a special page in their docs for using this library on app engine: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

This is how I use the `googleapiclient` library. One difference I see is this line:

`credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from lib.googleapiclient import discovery

class DataFlowJobsListHandler(AdminResourceHandler):

    def get(self, resource_id=None):
        """
        Wrapper to this:
        https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list
        """
        if resource_id:
            self.abort(405)
        else:
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
            service = discovery.build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
            project_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
            _filter = self.request.GET.pop('filter', 'UNKNOWN').upper()

            jobs_list_request = service.projects().jobs().list(
                projectId=project_id,
                filter=_filter)  #'ACTIVE'
            jobs_list = jobs_list_request.execute()

            return {
                '$cursor': None,
                'results': jobs_list.get('jobs', []),
            }
```

Comment: I've just tried making that credentials change with no luck. I suspect the error has something to do with the `body` parameter being in json. I wasn't able to find any examples where a json parameter is involved